# OnTopReplica alternative for Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, always-on-top

[OnTopReplica](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/ontopreplica) is a Windows application that allows you to clone a window then crop a subregion of it and keep it always on top (useful if you're trying to keep a YouTube Video always showing).

Is there any alternative for Linux installations (specifically Ubuntu or Linux Mint)? I tried looking for some sort of Compiz plugin that could emulate this, but I'm not sure where to start...

Comment: Would it be enough to size the window to the portion you want, remove the decorations (title bar etc) and make the resulting window always-on-top?  Most window managers can do this.

Comment: That requires so much more work on the end-user with less features (for example, OnTopReplica allows you to resize the region you crop to zoom in or out on it easily).

Comment: Yeah I figured, thought it was worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

I use ontopreplica all the time on Windows, I have bookmarked [this](http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/#download) a long time ago, not sure if the functionality is the same or if it follows your mouse.
Maybe try a on browser solution, if its especially for video there is [plenty of options.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/popup%20video?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon&_category=extensions)